# Why is the default fork-join pool always started when sending a request using JDK's HttpClient?

Tags: java, multithreading, httpclient, executorservice

I'm trying to send an HTTP request using the `HttpClient` bundled with Java (tested using JDK17), but using a custom thread pool / executor. Such an executor can be specified when building the client, as in the code below:

```java
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        var executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        var client = HttpClient.newBuilder().executor(executor).build();

        client.sendAsync(
                HttpRequest
                        .newBuilder()
                        .uri(URI.create("https://www.google.com"))
                        .build(),
                HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream()
        ).get();

        System.out.println("Done");
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

However, some additional threads are always started. One is a `SelectorManager`, which is hard-coded to be started [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.net.http/share/classes/jdk/internal/net/http/HttpClientImpl.java#L507-L531). It has a clear scope and probably needs to be a separate thread.

Additionally, when using `.sendAsync`, the default fork-join pool is also *always* started. I think this is due to the [following code in `HttpClient`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.net.http/share/classes/jdk/internal/net/http/HttpClientImpl.java#L990-L995):

```java
// makes sure that any dependent actions happen in the CF default
// executor. This is only needed for sendAsync(...), when
// exchangeExecutor is non-null.
if (exchangeExecutor != null) {
    res = res.whenCompleteAsync((r, t) -> { /* do nothing */}, ASYNC_POOL);
}
```

I suspect this is needed to always shift any further processing of the response (which might block) to another thread pool (to avoid blocking the thread that processes incoming HTTP data). However:

1. shouldn't this shifting happen onto the provided executor, instead of shifting to `ASYNC_POOL` always?
2. is my justification for the existence of the above `HttpClient` snippet correct?
3. maybe there are other reasons why the ForkJoin pool must be started?